# Kill Excel process that remains open in the background after closing file

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a program where I open and migrate an Excel file into another main file. I would like to delete it afterward. When I try to delete the file, I get a permission denied error.

After researching online, I did see I made some mistakes and then made sure to properly close the file and destroy related objects but I'm still getting the error.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim app as New Excel.Application
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb.app.Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH & "\filename.csv") 
    'I know the filepath is correct as I can open and manipulate the file

    '... Do things

    wb.close
    Set wb = Nothing
    kill FILEPATH & "\filename.csv"
    'I plan on adding error handling once the basic function works
End Sub
```

> Run-time error '70': Permission denied

EDIT: After playing with debugging I can say that I can successfully destroy the object, but the Excel process stays open in the background, I have to manually kill it in task manager for the code to work.

EDIT2: I solved my problem. I wanted to run this program outside of Excel through a VB script. I ran it through that, not having Excel opened before. Everything deletes properly.

Comment: hi. the file is still open. maybe its asking to save... try with     wb.Close SaveChanges:=False      .

Comment: Did you handle `app` as well?

Comment: What do you mean by handle app?

Comment: Well... you said you destroyed related objects, is `app` one of them?

Comment: Oh I didn't destroy app, should I have?

Comment: I'm curious why you need `app` - is this code in Excel already or in another program?

Comment: So earlier in the program I wanted certain application features like screen updating on the main file without the file-to-be-migrated. Also, I tried to destroy app, no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example with your code and works fine for me:

```
Sub Test()
Dim app As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim path As String
path = "your path"

Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path & "\dati.xlsx")
'I know the filepath is correct as I can open and manipulate the file

'... Do things
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E20").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wb.Close

Set wb = Nothing

Kill path & "\dati.xlsx"
'I plan on adding error handling once the basic function works
End Sub
```

I have created the file dati.xlsx.I Copy the range A1:E20 from the sheet1 (file data.xlsx) and paste the data into sheet1(sheet where is the macro). The result is the data and delete the file data.xlsx

> Pay Attantion in your post code when you write Set wb.app.... there
>   there is an error...

Comment: I see the error sorry about that. I wrote out the problem section of my code and made a typo. This could be an issue with my job's security measures as well. Might not allow users to run deletion scripts or something like that.